# Initialising array to a dynamic size - C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, multidimensional-array, system.data.sqlite

I am using an array to hold the results of an SQLite query, at the moment I am using a two dimensional table to do this.

The problem that I have is that I have to manually specify the size of one of the indexes before the array can be used but it feels like a waste as I have no real knowledge of how many rows will be returned. I do use a property which allows me to retrieve the amount of columns that are present which is used in the arrays initialisation.

**Example:**

```
using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
       results = new object[10,dr.FieldCount];

       while (dr.Read())
       {
            jIterator++;

            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                    results[jIterator, i] = dr.GetValue(i);
            }
       }
}
//I know there are a few count bugs
```

**Example Storage:**

[image: Array contents]

I simply add the data to the array for as long as the while loop returns true, in this instance I set the first index to 10 as I already know how many elements are in the database and 10 will be more than enough.

How would I go about changing the array so it's size can be dynamic, Is this even possible based on the way I am getting the database results?

Comment: Use a list kind of type that contains another list or custom class.
List<CustomClass> lst = new List<CustomClass>(); And let you're customclass contain the data (or just use another list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not be using an array, you should be using a dynamically-sized container like `List<T>`. Or, better yet, you could use something like the ADO.NET `DataTable`, since this is exactly what it's designed to store, and using a `DbDataAdapter` will avoid having to repeat the same `IDataReader` code all over the place.

Comment: But of course, I can't believe I never thought to use the generic list, thanks!

Comment: @Jamie: most of the time you should stay clear of arrays. Unless it's a `byte[]`, you should consider a container from System.Collections.Generic first.

Comment: I think I need more sleep or something, I almost always use generic collections but never thought to use it in this instance.

Comment: DataTable works very nicely by the way, binds to a DataGridView and populates everything automatically. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 9):

Don't use an array. Use a generic list `System.Collections.Generic.List<type>`, you can even have a List of a List. These are resizable and do all of that plumbing for you.

Comment: +1. And the number of elements you will get using Count proeprty.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest defining a structure to hold your contact information, then just creating a generic list of that type. They can expand without limit.

Comment: The biggest benefit of defining a type is you can address the members by name, rather than index: i.e.:Kodak.email rather than results[3][2].

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Use a `List<T[]>` instead of a 2 dimensional array.
- Load your datareader into  a dataset instead of an array
- Skip the datareader entirely and use a dataadapter to fill a dataset
- Use an iterator block to transform the datareader into an IEnumerable instead of an array

Of these, in most cases by far your best option is the last; it means you don't need to have the entire result set of your query in memory at one time, which is the main point for using an SqlDataReader in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic arrays in C#.

```
int[] intarray;
```

Although other responses that suggest List may be more appropriate.

Comment: Please consider providing a better code example. The current one *declares* a variable of type array. It does not *create* an array, and much less a dynamic array.